# Why can I get a Bluebird catch in the middle of chain stop the rest of the chain execution

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I am building this promise chain. The goal is to have the first action check for uniqueness on a field in the DB, and then if unique, save the object. But if the object is not unique, it should not save, and should return an error response.

```
function(request, reply) {
  var payload = request.payload;

  checkThatEmailDoesNotExist().then(saveUser)

  function checkThatEmailDoesNotExist() {
    return User.where({email: payload.email}).countAsync()
      .then(function(count) {
        if (count > 0) {
          throw Boom.badRequest('The email provided for this user already exists')
        }

        return null;
      })
      .catch(function(err) { // ~This catch should stop the promise chain~
        reply(err);
      })
  }

  function saveUser() {
    // ~But instead it is continuing on to this step~
    return User.massAssign(request.payload).saveAsync()
      .spread(function(user, numAffected) {
        return reply(user);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        server.log(['error', 'api', 'auth'], err);
        throw Boom.badRequest('Object could not be saved to database');
      });
  }
}
```

If an error is thrown in the `checkThatEmailDoesNotExist()` it's `catch()` should return the error, and stop processing the rest of the original promise chain.

Instead of acting that way, the `catch()` fires, and then continues to move on to the `saveUser()` function.

Comment: The catch proceeds "successfully" and returns a promise which is resolved (fulfilled). So chained `then`'s **will** be executed. To avoid that, throw the error again within the `catch` function. To put it another way, you could say that rejections are caught just once along the chain (unless the catch handler itself rethrows). By the way, this is on the boundary of what some say promises should be used for. Normally, rejections indicate some extraordinary situation. Here, you're using them for some plain old duplicate checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing promises and callbacks which is a horrible anti-pattern. The caller will simply use 
the returned promise, there is no need to manually wire things back to callbacks.

```
function save(request) {
  var payload = request.payload;

    return User.where({email: payload.email}).countAsync()
      .then(function(count) {
        if (count > 0) {
          throw Boom.badRequest('The email provided for this user already exists')
        }

        return User.massAssign(request.payload).saveAsync()
      })
      .get(0)
      /* equivalent to 
      .spread(function(user, numAffected) {
        return user;
      }) */
      .catch(Promise.OperationalError, function(err) {
        server.log(['error', 'api', 'auth'], err);
        throw Boom.badRequest('Object could not be saved to database');
      });
}
```

Usage:

```
save(request).then(function(user) {
    response.render(...)
}).catch(function(e) {
    response.error(...)
})
```

If you wanted to expose a callback api, the sane way to do that is to bolt on a nodeify at the end of an existing promise api and call it a day:

```
function save(request, callback) {
  var payload = request.payload;

    return User.where({email: payload.email}).countAsync()
      .then(function(count) {
        if (count > 0) {
          throw Boom.badRequest('The email provided for this user already exists')
        }

        return User.massAssign(request.payload).saveAsync()
      })
      .get(0)
      /* equivalent to 
      .spread(function(user, numAffected) {
        return user;
      }) */
      .catch(Promise.OperationalError, function(err) {
        server.log(['error', 'api', 'auth'], err);
        throw Boom.badRequest('Object could not be saved to database');
      })
      .nodeify(callback);
}

save(request, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return response.error(...);
    response.render(...);
});
```